# How can I view the ecommerce conversation rate for users who triggered a custom event in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, analytics-events, google-analytics-4, google-data-studio

In Google Universal Analytics I used to create segments of users who triggered a custom event. After creating them I could use these in comparisons on dashboards but also in custom Data Studio (Looker Studio) reports.

I'm looking for a way to do this in Google Analytics 4.

So far I've tried these things:

1. Setup audiences, this works except it isn't retroactive and there's a limit of 20 audiences. I need more because I have at least 20 custom events with a couple of different custom events with custom dimensions.
2. Use explorations. First explorations look bad in contrast to what you can do in Data Studio. Also when I create a Funnel exploration with a step in which I choose a custom event and set the parameter filter to: custom dimension x contains y. It updates the summary to 0 users, but I am sure there are users who match this criteria. When I don't add the parameter filter it does work (though it doesn't show what I want) but it sets the sample rate to 11%. So the data is not at all reliable.
3. Use promotion. I tried using promotions via promotion_view and promotions_select, but the promotions are missing a conversion rate. This is because you need to send the promotion id with the purchase event. But this means other promotions, like internal banners are overwritten, that's also not what I want.

Is there anyone who can help me figure out how I can get the ecommerce conversion rate for users that triggered a custom event?
Thanks!

Comment: Just curious. You want to know the user purchase after the custom event or it's okay if user purchase then trigger the custom event. 
Maybe you can share more about the segment in your looker studio then everyone can provide some ideas